# Interactive console in the middle of flash debugging(flash builder 4)

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I tried to search, but couldn't find anything on the topic.
In many languages in eclipse you can execute code in the middle of debug session.
Usually it's done through the console.

Is there a way to do the same thing in the Flash Builder?

EDIT: Ok, i'll to explain better. Is there a way to execute some code in the middle of the debug session?
Like in python you can type in console in pydev(eclipse) when the program is paused(being debugged) and run any code you want.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean.

Comment: ^ I've tried to explain better ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why look!

http://code.google.com/p/flash-console/

HTH :)

Comment: AWESOME! Shame adobe don't support it out of the box in flex sdk though. Many thanks, debugging and testing will be much faster now!

Comment: No kidding, talk about a great feature to have out of the box.  Enjoy!